# $dateRange is undefined

Tags: php, calendar, laravel-8, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=4

However, I did not manage to list all the events in my calendar. I was able to dump json file by using this:

```
return response()->json($events);
```

However, after replacing that line with:

```
$viewData['events'] = $events;
return view('calendar', $viewData);
```

I received this error:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: dateRange (View:
> C:\Users\syahm\FWIMS\resources\views\calendar.blade.php)
> http://localhost:8000/calendar Hide solutions $dateRange is undefined

My controller.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<h1>Calendar</h1>
<h2>{{ $dateRange }}</h2>
<a class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-3" href={{action('CalendarController@getNewEventForm')}}>New event</a>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Organizer</th>
      <th scope="col">Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Start</th>
      <th scope="col">End</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @isset($events)
      @foreach($events as $event)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $event->getOrganizer()->getEmailAddress()->getName() }}</td>
          <td>{{ $event->getSubject() }}</td>
          <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($event->getStart()->getDateTime())->format('n/j/y g:i A') }}</td>
          <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($event->getEnd()->getDateTime())->format('n/j/y g:i A') }}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    @endif
  </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

My CalendarController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
use App\TokenStore\TokenCache;
use App\TimeZones\TimeZones;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
  public function calendar()
  {
    $viewData = $this->loadViewData();

    $graph = $this->getGraph();

    // Get user's timezone
    $timezone = TimeZones::getTzFromWindows($viewData['userTimeZone']);

    // Get start and end of week
    $startOfWeek = new \DateTimeImmutable('monday -1 week', $timezone);
    $endOfWeek = new \DateTimeImmutable('monday', $timezone);

    $queryParams = array(
      'startDateTime' => $startOfWeek->format(\DateTimeInterface::ISO8601),
      'endDateTime' => $endOfWeek->format(\DateTimeInterface::ISO8601),
      // Only request the properties used by the app
      '$select' => 'subject,organizer,start,end',
      // Sort them by start time
      '$orderby' => 'start/dateTime',
      // Limit results to 25
      '$top' => 25
    );

    // Append query parameters to the '/me/calendarView' url
    $getEventsUrl = '/me/calendarView?'.http_build_query($queryParams);

    $events = $graph->createRequest('GET', $getEventsUrl)
      // Add the user's timezone to the Prefer header
      ->addHeaders(array(
        'Prefer' => 'outlook.timezone="'.$viewData['userTimeZone'].'"'
      ))
      ->setReturnType(Model\Event::class)
      ->execute();

      $viewData['events'] = $events;
      return view('calendar', $viewData);
  }

  private function getGraph(): Graph
  {
    // Get the access token from the cache
    $tokenCache = new TokenCache();
    $accessToken = $tokenCache->getAccessToken();

    // Create a Graph client
    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    return $graph;
  }
}
```

Added 'dd($viewData);' to my calendarcontroller.php and I received this:

```
array:4 [▼
  "userName" => "ABC"
  "userEmail" => "ABC@localhost"
  "userTimeZone" => "Eastern Standard Time"
  "events" => array:3 [▼
    0 => Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event {#310 ▼
      #_propDict: array:6 [▼
        "@odata.etag" => "W/"3ixz55KajUefR0tOGmhiSQABIRK5QA==""
        "id" => "AAMkAGZlZWE2N2ZlLTczM2ItNDI2Ny05NWU0LTZmOWFiNzZmZmJhZABGAAAAAAC85uAHa4F5RpnXBxFnN2zgBwDeLHPnkpqNR59HS04aaGJJAAAAAAENAADeLHPnkpqNR59HS04aaGJJAAEhezxbAAA="
        "subject" => "AA 2"
        "start" => array:2 [▼
          "dateTime" => "2020-11-23T09:30:00.0000000"
          "timeZone" => "Eastern Standard Time"
        ]
        "end" => array:2 [▼
          "dateTime" => "2020-11-23T16:30:00.0000000"
          "timeZone" => "Eastern Standard Time"
        ]
        "organizer" => array:1 [▼
          "emailAddress" => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "AA"
            "address" => "AA@localhost"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
    1 => Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event {#296 ▼
      #_propDict: array:6 [▼
        "@odata.etag" => "W/"3ixz55KajUefR0tOGmhiSQABIl5/QA==""
        "id" => "AAMkAGZlZWE2N2ZlLTczM2ItNDI2Ny05NWU0LTZmOWFiNzZmZmJhZABGAAAAAAC85uAHa4F5RpnXBxFnN2zgBwDeLHPnkpqNR59HS04aaGJJAAAAAAENAADeLHPnkpqNR59HS04aaGJJAAEhezxcAAA="
        "subject" => "AA 3"
        "start" => array:2 [▼
          "dateTime" => "2020-11-25T09:30:00.0000000"
          "timeZone" => "Eastern Standard Time"
        ]
        "end" => array:2 [▼
          "dateTime" => "2020-11-25T16:30:00.0000000"
          "timeZone" => "EasternStandard Time"
        ]
        "organizer" => array:1 [▼
          "emailAddress" => array:2 [▶]
        ]
      ]
    }
    2 => Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event {#306 ▼
      #_propDict: array:6 [▼
        "@odata.etag" => "W/"3ixz55KajUefR0tOGmhiSQABIwjzEw==""
        "id" => "AAMkAGZlZWE2N2ZlLTczM2ItNDI2Ny05NWU0LTZmOWFiNzZmZmJhZABGAAAAAAC85uAHa4F5RpnXBxFnN2zgBwDeLHPnkpqNR59HS04aaGJJAAAAAAENAADeLHPnkpqNR59HS04aaGJJAAEjdLLVAAA="
        "subject" => "AA 4/2020 "
        "start" => array:2 [▼
          "dateTime" => "2020-11-26T14:30:00.0000000"
          "timeZone" => "Eastern Standard Time"
        ]
        "end" => array:2 [▼
          "dateTime" => "2020-11-26T16:00:00.0000000"
          "timeZone" => "Eastern Standard Time"
        ]
        "organizer" => array:1 [▼
          "emailAddress" => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "AA"
            "address" => "AA@localhost"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: The likely cause is that `$viewData['dateRange']` doesn't exist, so you're not passing a variable `$dateRanges` to your view. Do a `dd($viewData);` before `return view('calendar', $viewData);`, and add the output to your question (please don't post it in the comments, edit your question and add it there)

Comment: Did as told and has edited my question to include the output. Thank you!

Comment: As I suspected :) So, since `$viewData` only has `userName`, `userEmail`, `userTimeZone` and `events`, and those are converted to variables, `$userName`, `$userEmail`, `$userTimeZone` and `$events`, `$dateRanges` is not available. You'll need to add some logic to make `$viewData['dateRanges']` exist.

Comment: It is now showing the error: 'Undefined index: userTimeZone' but in my controller, i already defined the userTimeZone?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have managed to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

Removed this from my calendar.blade.php and it is now working!

```
<h2>{{ $dateRange }}</h2>
<a class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-3" href={{action('CalendarController@getNewEventForm')}}>New event</a>
```